# Errore while using parameters in sub-function (i think)

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, parameter-passing

i'm having this issue while copying a portion of code from a blog.

I have no idea what this syntax is, it looks like a function that is passed as a parameter inside a function, but it's giving me this problem, that I can't use the variables that I pass to the parent function

[This is the function, and this is where the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BaS8.png)

[The error is the following one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsyUQ.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me solve this problem

Comment: just use funtion(data:any, filter:any)=>....

Comment: But i need the value that i declared above, not a new value

Comment: Please post (minimal) code examples, error messages as formatted text, not as images or links to images.